# Does making a builder class to create JLabels make swing components load faster?

Tags: java, swing, class, jlabel

Suppose I have the following code to make a JLabel:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Test");
label.setBounds(6, 5, 538, 15);
.
. (Edit Other Properties Here)
.
```

I also have a class called "CustomJLabel", which is shown here"

```
public class CustomJLabel extends JLabel {

   public CustomJLabel(int x, int y, int width, int height, String text) {

       this.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
       this.setText(text);

   }

}
```

Of course, in the case of only having 1 or a few JLabels, the builder class (CustomJLabel) isn't necessary. However, I found many programmers use these builder classes as practice. However, the question here is that **if you had 100 JLabels, each initialized with their own properties, would it be more efficient for a programmer to use the Builder class?** From my experience, using a builder class greatly improves code readability and how many lines of code you need to type.

Comment: *"components load faster?"* I wouldn't think so.  Builder patterns are great for introducing imperative style development, rather then relying on setters directly. You could also make use of various factory patterns to apply some common properties as needed.  I would look towards what makes your life easier based on your needs

Comment: There is no chance that this will be faster (though it probably isn’t noticeably slower either).  And writing fewer lines does not make code more readable.  If anything, using a custom class is less readable than using a standard class like JLabel whose behavior is thoroughly documented in a stable location.  Why not just make a private method that builds a JLabel?  A custom class that does nothing but standard configuration of a JLabel is pointless bloat and a misuse of inheritance.

Comment: What you’ve created is not a builder class. It’s an unnecessary subclass. A builder does not extend the type it’s producing.